# onedrive for business webhooks

Tags: webhooks, onedrive

I can't seem to find the correct way to subscribe to webhooks for onedrive for business.

I know the endpoint url is different then regular onedrive.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences)

So according to the docs the endpoint to subscribe to webhooks should be the following:

https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/subscriptions

But when I send a POST request to this endpoint I get a 404.

Getting the drive items via this endpoint works as expected.
(https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0//drive/special/approot). 
Only the "subscriptions" endpoint I can't seem to access.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions are applied to items, so you'll want:

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/subscriptions
```

The docs seem a little ambiguous in that regard.